# WordPress/Elementor Real-Time Traffic Alerts via Email

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm looking for a way to receive real-time alerts, via email, whenever someone visits a specific URL on my website.

- The website is built with WordPress Multisite and Elementor
- The URL is coming from a QR code and there are custom variables in the URL that will be different for every person that receives our postcard
- We want an email notification every time someone visits the URL. The email should contain the specific URL that was visited so we have the visitor's info

Can anyone suggest a creative way to get this done?

Comment: well, don't know if it's the best method but maybe get the custom values with PHP and use the wp_mail() or PHPMailer() function to email you with the value inside ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It looks as though you're trying to get someone to write code for you which is not what this website is for _ Please add any code attempt that you've tried. You should also visit SO Help Center 'Asking' section to find out more about submitting a properly formatted question >>> stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager which I think could work well for you.

- Install Universal Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager on your site
- In GTM, create an additional tag that fires on all pages

  - Track Type: Event
  - Category: Page View
  - Label: Hit the + and choose Page URL
  - Set this tag to fire on all pages
- In Google Analytics, go to Customization > Custom Alerts

  - Manage Custom Alerts > New Alert
  - Name the alert, set the period as Day, check 'Send me an email with this alert is triggered'
  - Alert me when: Total Events > 0
  - Save

The end result of this is that every time there's a page view on your site, GTM will trigger an event which will be recorded to GA. Event details will include the page URL.

And you'll get daily email alerts every time there's at least one page view on your site.

While this may not be exactly what you describe, it has what I think are good advantages, because GA will take care of recording all the details for you, and you'll be able to slice and dice the results like any other GA data.

To examine the results in GA, go to Behaviour > Events > Overview > Event Category.

Then set the primary dimension as 'Event Label' and you'll have a wealth of info.

You'll see not only the individual URLs, but also page views over time for each user, total page views by user, and total global page views to name a few.

If you have more than just a custom URL in your QR code, maybe you'll even be able to push that into GA as well, via an event action or event value in GTM ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work because we need these notifications in real-time for our sales team. But thanks for the idea.